# MYSQL SQL pass value from executed to a subsequent sql statement

Tags: mysql

I am writing a migration script to copy data from custom tables on the old site to wordpress style table on the new site.

Orginally, I thought I could get away with just creating SQL statements and then using insert staements to create the new data on the wordpress tables.

Example

`Categories` Table on old system: `ID`, `NAME`, `SEQUENCE`

`Subcatoegories` on old system: `ID`, `NAME`, `PARENT_ID`, `SEQUENCE`

I realize now that the ID for categories is an auto_increment field so I won't know its value until after it is inserted. Therefor I cannot provide a value for `PARENT_ID` for the subcategories SQL.

```
Insert into wp_categories (NAME,SEQUENCE) values ('MUSIC',1);
```

That will work fine but I cannot  figure out how to pass the generated ID value to the next SQL statement

```
Insert into wp_subcategories (NAME,PARENT_ID,SEQUENCE) values ('ROCK MUSIC',1, ???);
```

The 3 question marks being the inserted value of ID in the previous SQL statement. Is it possible to do this or am I going to have to write some PHP script to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) like

```
Insert into wp_subcategories (NAME,PARENT_ID,SEQUENCE) 
values ('ROCK MUSIC', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1);
```

Per your comment; store the value in a local variable and use that local variable instead like

```
Insert into wp_categories (NAME,SEQUENCE) values ('MUSIC',1);

SET @categoru_PK = LAST_INSERT_ID();

Insert into wp_subcategories (NAME,PARENT_ID,SEQUENCE) values ('ROCK MUSIC',1, @categoru_PK);

Insert into wp_subcategories (NAME,PARENT_ID,SEQUENCE) values ('SAD MUSIC',2, @categoru_PK);
```

Comment: WOW - nice and simple - let me try it and then vote on the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately there a more than 1 subcategories to the main category so it won't work. The main category will be added and the next sql for subcategories will work but then I need to add another subcategory after that and the last insert ID will be of the subcategory not the main category.

Comment: In that case, store the value in a local variable and use that local variable instead. See edit in answer.

Comment: Rahul, that's exactly what I was looking for. I did not know you could set local variables like this. Thanks a lot!!!